# asp button inside jquery accordion not raising server event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using jquery UI accordion. Inside the accordion, there are some textboxes and asp button. When I click the button the server event is not firing. But the OnClientClick is fired.

Neither of the asp buttons inside accordion is fired, why is it so?

```
<asp:Content ID="UserContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        });

        function BtnTrigger() {
            alert("button pressed");
        }
    </script>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Change Password</h3>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <b>Previous Password: :</b>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_prev_pwd" TextMode="Password" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"  MaxLength="15" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqd_txtpwd" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter the password" ControlToValidate="txt_prev_pwd" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <b>New Password :</b>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_new_pwd" TextMode="Password" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"  MaxLength="15" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rqd_txt_new_pwd" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter the new password" ControlToValidate="txt_new_pwd" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_pwd" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btn_pwd_Click" />
        </div>
        <h3>Change Department</h3>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
            <b>Department :</b>
            <asp:ListBox ID="listBoxDepartment" runat="server" Rows="1" Width="300px"></asp:ListBox>
        </div>
            </div>
            <asp:Button ID="btn_chng_depart" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btn_chng_depart_Click" OnClientClick="BtnTrigger();" />
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>

// code behind
protected void btn_chng_depart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                // code
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try any of the following fixes.

- Add `CausesValidation="false"` to the buttons
- If the `OnClientClick` handle creates an exception, the postback is cancelled. make sure you `return true;` as well.
- Make sure the buttons are inside a `<asp:form runat="server">` tag
- Remove the javascript `alert` just in case
- Do you have `AutoEventWireup="true"` set in your page directive?

  - Try wiring the event on page load: `btn_pwd.Click += new EventHandler(btn_pwd_Click);`

Hope this helps